# Building a GWT UI in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, google-plugin-eclipse, gui-designer, gwt-designer

I want to try and build a UI using this GWT designer tool I read about.  I have GWT tools installed,  created a "Google -> Web Application Project" but I don't see any means to build a UI except via code. 
I tried installing the plugin 
http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/3.7
but it fails ( Not sure if I need this or not )

This is the tutorial I was looking at ..... How do I get this UI design view?
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/quick_start

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative to using the GWT Designer, if you don't want to use UiBinder, is

1. In Eclipse, right-click view class in Package Explorer
2. Open With
3. GWT Designer
4. Select the Designer tab at the bottom of the class window.

[image]

Comment: If you don't use UiBinder, then your class needs to extend `com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Composite` before you can edit it with GWT Designer. (Which is unfortunate, because it's often preferable to implement `IsWidget` instead.)

Comment: That's not true. You are able to extend your class to any subclass of Widget and still use GWT Designer, though, I suppose it only makes sense to extend Panel, or any subclass of Panel.

Comment: What I had tried was opening GWT designer on a view class that extends `Widget` directly - and that fails with "Graphical editing is not provided for Widget". But I stand corrected, your class doesn't have to be a subclass of Composite, it can be any *sub-sub* class of Widget (quite strange actually). Many people, maybe including the OP, probably wonder, why the Designer doesn't open for their view classes which might only implement `IsWidget` without extending a subclass of `Widget`.

Answer (score 0):

First from new file dialogue ( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> ) create a UiBinder file (xxx.ui.xml):

[image]

Then select "Design" from left bottom of opened file in eclipse.

[image]

Comment: I am not getting design option